# Django throws error on model field for wrong database

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

I have two databases set up for my Django project, a MySQL and a Postgres.

I have a database router in place and everything has been working fine, until I changed a `CharField` with `max_length` of 300 in a Postgres model to unique.

That model is in Postgres, but now Django throws this error about MySQL:

`[postgres_app.TestModel.slug]: (mysql.E001) MySQL does not allow unique CharFields to have a max_length > 255.`

I double checked my database router and everything looked fine. I also have to mention again the router was doing its job correctly before and picked the correct database for read, write, and migration. Here is my router:

```
POSTGRES_APPS = ['postgres_app']


class PostgresRouter(object):
    """ Controls which apps can have access to the postgres instance. """

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """ Called on every read action on a model. """
        if model._meta.app_label in POSTGRES_APPS:
            return 'postgres'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """ Called on every write action on a model. """
        if model._meta.app_label in POSTGRES_APPS:
            return 'postgres'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """ Called only on migrations. Only allow relations if both models are in POSTGRES_APPS. """
        return {obj1._meta.app_label, obj2._meta.app_label}.issubset(set(POSTGRES_APPS)) or None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """ Called only on migrations. """
        if db == 'postgres':
            return app_label in POSTGRES_APPS
        else:
            return app_label not in POSTGRES_APPS
```

and this is my model:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
```

So the question is whether it is a bug in Django or not, and if not, then how can I tell Django it is looking at the wrong database.